# webrequest, Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (400) Demande incorrecte

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project or I need to send data to a server using TSL 1.2 security by the post method. In the header I send the following authentication key and in the body the object JSON when I execute my code I have this error

> *Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (400) Demande incorrecte.

My framework version is 4.6, I use asp.net and C#

```
 public string SendData(string urlRessource, string dataHeader)
   {
       string responseFromServer = "";
       try
       {
            //ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
           string http = urlRessource;
           var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http);
           httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
           httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
           httpWebRequest.Timeout = 5000000;
           httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
           httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json;";
           httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("auth", AppSetting.HEADERAUTH);
           Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataHeader);
           httpWebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
           {

               streamWriter.Write(dataHeader);
               streamWriter.Flush();
               streamWriter.Close();

               var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
               using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
               {
                   responseFromServer = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
               }
           }


       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           ResponseApi api = new ResponseApi
           {
               code = 500,
               message = ex.Message,
               exceptionLine = ex.StackTrace
           };
           responseFromServer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(api, Formatting.Indented);

       }


       Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
       Console.ReadLine();

       return responseFromServer;
   }
```

My data is:

```
 string headerData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
                                senderFirstName = "hfh",
                                senderLastName = "fssdf",
                                senderPhone = "67457487",
                                amount = 20,


                                }, Formatting.Indented);
```

The link to the resource is ok when I send my request using postman everything goes well but by the code nothing

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddle and compare the http header in the postman request with the one in your application that is not working.  Make the c# app look like postman.  Usually it requires changing a header or adding a missing header.  TLS is encryption.  HTTP uses TCP for transport layer.  TCP max datagram is ~1500 bytes. A HTTP message consist of one or more TCP.  The TLS is implemented at the TCP layer so you may have to look at the TCP layer.

Comment: "fiddler" is the name of the network inspection tool